# Телеграм бот выводит свое имя, а не имя пользователя

Tags: python, telebot

У меня есть такой код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def welcome(message):
    telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    pol = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    policy_agree = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Принять", callback_data="polagree")
    pol.add(policy_agree)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Нажимая кнопку Принять, Вы соглашаетесь с нашей [Политикой конфедициальности](https://telegra.ph/Politika-v-otnoshenii-obrabotki-personalnyh-dannyh-WarloxShop-09-11)",parse_mode='MarkdownV2', reply_markup=pol)
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: "polagree" )

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: "polagree" )
def callback_inline(call):
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,"Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот для покупки софта, игр и различных подписок на разные сервисы".format(call.message.from_user, bot.get_me()),parse_mode='html',reply_markup=markup)
```

После того, как я добавил функцию `welcome`, бот в приветствии начал писать свое имя вместо `{0.first_name}`. Как можно исправить?

Comment: Что такое 0.first_name? Вы у числа атрибут first_name хотите получить?

Comment: @MyZik эту часть кода писал не я, если честно. Если будет понятнее, то я могу вместо ```{0.first_name}``` указать ```call.message.from_user.first_name```

Comment: @MyZik не понял как, но баг перестал воспроизводиться

Comment: Указал ```call.from_user.first_name``` вместо ```{0.first_name}```. Баг воспроизводился, но спустя несколько перезапусков, он пропал. Сам не понял что произошло